# Shorten Azure AD Access Token Lifetime for Desktop App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I'm trying to shorten the lifetime for a Azure AD access token, so that I can verify that MSAL.NET is automatically refreshing the token when acquiring the token silently in my .NET desktop app.

I can find documentation on how to do this for a  [B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow), as well as how to do it for a  [web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in) which doesn't seem appropriate. Is there a way for me to do this on the Azure Portal similar to the B2C route? This seems like a relatively basic token configuration option I'm confused at the lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The document you provided ([B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow)) showing the steps for Azure ad b2c seems to be appropriate in your case to set the access token life time through portal.Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop) .

But if that’s not working as expected then you can say  Configurable token lifetime policy only applies to mobile and desktop clients that access SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business resources, and does not apply to web browser sessions.

To manage the lifetime of web browser sessions for SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business, use the Conditional Access session lifetime feature. To configure token-lifetimes via conditional access policy .
See this [reference](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/azure-active-directorys-configurable-token-lifetimes/)

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried all of these. The B2C steps do not work since this isn't a B2C tenant, and the instructions can't be translated over to a normal one. 

This actually is for a desktop client and not a web browser session. I did try the Conditional Access feature, but it only allows you to set the lifetime of the refresh token and not the access token.